Swagger Configuration Issue
I have configured swagger for my springboot application but when I am accessing the swagger ui my schemas are visible however the values inside them (variables of the schema class) are not visible
Using springboot 3.1.6 & springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui 2.3.0
I have tried checking for version compatibility but this didn't seem to be an issue as I have done similar configurations in a different application where this issue didn't occur.


Share your request and response POJO classes
